# How to create a soft body trampoline?

Tags: modeling, physics, cloth-simulation

**How to create a trampoline using Blender physics simulator?**

The bouncing and collision location is correct. Only the ball does not "dent" the trampoline needs to be fixed. Increasing soft body mass causes the ball to stick to the cloth. Increasing cloth collision quality does not help (ball sticks to cloth). "Bake all Dynamics" gives the same result.

| Mass = 1 kg | Mass = 10 kg |
| --- | --- |
| [image: video] | [image: video] |
| [image] |  |
| Blender 3.5.1 on Linux |  |

I almost manage with:

- plane (5m x 5m, edge subdivided 10x10), all transforms applied

  - modifiers

    - Subdivide: 2
    - Cloth

      - Quality steps: 5
      - Shape

        - Pin group: plane edges
        - Shrinking factor: -0.01
      - Collisions

        - Quality: 5
    - Collision
- Icosphere

  - modifiers

    - Soft body

      - Object mass: 1 kg, 5 kg, 10 kg
      - Goal: disabled
      - Edges

        - Bending: 1

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file so that people can try without redoing the whole thing?

Comment: Yes, the file would be great. And I don't think the GIF generating code is in any way necessary for this question and only wasting space.

Comment: @moonboots updated post with Blend file and removed GIF code. Simulation is real time so I did not include physics cache (10 MB). I also saved with soft body pane open so it is easy to change 1 kg to 10 kg.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing is that the Icosphere also needs a Collision modifier. Shrinking factor can be 0 or small positive.

[image: render]